# AWS Lambda as Reverse proxy for Grafana

Tags: lambda, grafana, reverse-proxy

We are trying to use AWS lambda as Reverse proxy for Grafana and using node JS for lambda.

Below is the lambda code:

```
const express = require('express');
   const app = express();
   const serverless = require('serverless-http');
   const port = 8000;
   const varenv = 'production';
   app.use(express.static('view'))
   var http = require('http');
   var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
   var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});
   proxy.on('proxyReq', function (proxyReq, req) {
      proxyReq.setHeader('X-WEBAUTH-USER', 'admin')
   });
   proxy.on('proxyRes', function (proxyRes, req, res) {
     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   });
   proxy.on('error', function (err, req, res) {
     res.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
     res.end("An error occured ....Susanta-101");
   });
 
   app.all("/*", function (req, res) {
     console.log("Forwarding to grafana server...")
     proxy.web(req, res, {
        target: 'http://stack-Grafa-1GNU1ALCSQL27-734749157.us-east- 
               1.elb.amazonaws.com/', // link to our target service
        secure: false
     });
   })

   if (varenv === 'production') {
     console.log("serverless block...!!!")
     exports.handler = serverless(app);
   } else {
     app.listen(port,
        () => console.log(`Susanta Listening on port ${port}!`))
   }
```

Also, connected the lambda to AWS api gateway and accessing through api url and getting the below errors:

[image: error screen]

If you're seeing this Grafana has failed to load its application files

1. This could be caused by your reverse proxy settings.
2. If you host grafana under subpath make sure your grafana.ini root_url setting includes subpath. If not using a reverse proxy make sure to set serve_from_sub_path to true.
3. If you have a local dev build make sure you build frontend using: yarn start, yarn start:hot, or yarn build
4. Sometimes restarting grafana-server can help
5. Check if you are using a non-supported browser. For more information, refer to the list of supported browsers.

Could you please help me out to resolve this one.

Thanks,
Susanta

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why don't you use any of ready maid widely supported reverse proxy. Perhaps, one of four, for which Grafana provide [example](https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/) of configuration? Any of them supports what is written in your script. Also, I'm sure AWS has a couple of reverse proxies too.

Comment: Thanks Markalex for your response, I have already crack the reverse proxy through nginx with linux EC2 for which we need to open a port in EC2 to access Nginx.

But as per requirement we cann't open a extra port in EC2 server due to some security reason, So I was finding a alternative way through serverless technology. could you pls suggest if it's possible?